# criptografia sha1 com python

Tags: python, json, sha1

Preciso gerar uma criptografia sha1 de um valor string de um arquivo JSON, mas não estou conseguindo. Alguém sabe onde estou errando no meu código? O código abre o arquivo json, pega a String que esta na chave campo1 transforma em sha1 e depois grava o valor na chave campo2, salva e fecha o arquivo json.

```
import requests
import json
import hashlib

arq = open('arq.json', 'r')
data = json.load(arq)
arq.close()

resumo = hashlib.sha1(data['campo1']).hexdigest()
data['campo2'] = resumo

arq = open('arq.json', 'w+')
arq.write(json.dumps(data))
arq.close()
```

Está dando um erro de encode TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: o que está acontecendo? o código parece correto. se a trutura externa do seu json for uma lista e não um dicionário, vai dar erro. Como você vai re-escrever o arquivo todo, o modo "w", e não "w+" deve ser usado.

Comment: está dando um erro de encode `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: Ah - agora é possível responder a questão, sem ter que (1) gravar seu código num programa local, (2) criar um JSON de exemplo "do nada" que seja compatível com o programa e (3) rodar o programa pra ver o erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas as funções criptográficas funcionam em cima de hashes, não em cima de texto. Já que um mesmo texto pode ter várias representações diferentes como bytes, dependendo do encoding escolhido.

O encoding usado no mundo inteiro, nos celulares e em supercomputação para textos é a codificação universal "utf-8". No entanto, o Windows continua, por motivos históricos, usando codificações locais para arquivos e filesystem. Tanto a codificação utf-8 quanto a latin-1 (usada pelo Windows em linguagens ocidentais) funcionariam bem aí - mas é importante que a codificação seja a mesma que já está no arquivo - então dá pra aproveitar que ele é aberto para leitura, e pegar a codificação usada pelo Python -

```
import requests
import json
import hashlib

with open('arq.json', 'r') as arq:  # Sintaxe recomendada para abrir arquivos - garante o close automático
   data = json.load(arq)
   encoding = arq.encoding


resumo = hashlib.sha1(data['campo1'].encode(encoding)).hexdigest()
data['campo2'] = resumo

with open('arq.json', 'w') as arq:
   json.dump(data, arq)
```